# How to remove lines with duplicate pair of words?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a file with multiple columns like

```
abc cvn bla..bla..n_columns
xnt yuk m_columns
abc cvn xxxx
vbh ast
sth rty
xnt yuk
```

I want to create a new file by comparing the repeated word pairs in first two columns.
The final file will look like

```
abc cvn bla..bla..n_columns
xnt yuk m_columns
vbh ast
sth rty
```

Comment: What do you mean with "by comparing the repeated word pairs in first two columns"? Why `vbh ast` is not in the sample output?

Comment: I just edited the post correctly

Comment: if the output sequence doesn't matter, seems `sort -u -k1,2 file` works. But if `abc cvn xxxx` appears before `abc cvn bla..bla..n_columns`, which one do you want to keep?

Comment: If abc cvn xxxx appears before abc cvn bla..bla..n_columns I just want to keep any of the line. It does not matter for me which line should be there. Any of the line will be okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is:

```
awk '!seen[$1,$2]++' file
```

Comment: +1!!! I was watching devnull's answer, and wanted to post a comment say, what if two lines: `aa bb` and `aab b`, but I thought it might be too picky. and his solution may work for OP....... Ed! master!

Comment: Kent & devnull - yeah, any time you see string concatenation being used in array indices a warning bell should go off. With newer gawk releases of course you can do `!seen[$1][$2]++` which is even safer since it doesn't rely on SUBSEP not being present in the input but then you need to state it's gawk-specific...

Comment: There are also some pairs like <br/>
yuk xnt <br/>
xnt yuk <br/>
xnt yuk <br/>
In such case I only want to keep any of one occurance. For me the A B pair is equal to B A pair. Could you help

Comment: `!(seen[A,B]++ || seen[B,A]++)`

Answer (score 0):

> If abc cvn xxxx appears before abc cvn bla..bla..n_columns I just want
>   to keep any of the line. It does not matter for me which line should
>   be there. Any of the line will be okay.

If the output sequence doesn't matter,  you can use `sort`

```
sort -u -k1,2 file
```

otherwise you should use `awk` as suggested by devnull

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 'H
$ {x
   s/$/\
/
: again
   s/\(\n\)\([^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}[^ [:cntrl:]]\{1,\}\)\(.*\)\1\2[^[:cntrl:]]*\n/\1\2\3\1/
   t again
   s/\n\(.*\)\n/\1/
   p
   }' YourFile
```

based on any repeated peer of value (pair is character not space or \n separate by "space") in whole text with a loop while there is a peer finnded and replaced.

**principle**

1. `H` Append each line (sed work line by line in work buffer) from working buffer into the hold buffer (there is a working buffer and a hold buffer)
2. `$` at the end
3. `x` swap working and hold buffer, so all the file is in working buffer but starting with a new line (due to Append action)
4. `s/...` Add a New line at the end (for later substitution process delimiter)
5. `: again` put a label anchor (for a later goto)
6. `s/...//` is the core of the process. Search a starting (after a new line) peer of word and a later same starting peer, if find, substitute the whole block with the part from start of block until second peer not included. (block start at first peer until new line on same line as second peer)
7. `t again` if substitution earlier is made, go to label `again`
8. `s/.../` remove the added new line at start and end
9. `p` print the result

Sed is trying always to take the mose of a pattern so if there is more than 2 peer of 1 of the uniq peer, it first remove the last peer and go back until there is only 1

Comment: Could you provide any insight into why someone might want to use that sed solution over the concise, trivial, sort and awk alternatives?

Comment: I wasn't asking how it works, I was asking if you could give us some idea as to why someone would want to do it that way given the alternatives.

Comment: limited by sed due to other action before, after or on the single peer for example, avoiding to pass through shell pipe.

Comment: the main interest is iof sed is already used for soem other action and thus no fork of shell process is needed passing through a AWK, grep or other tools. So not interesting if limited to the sample case.

Comment: You're suggesting someone might want to ADD that to an existing sed script???? No. No way on the face of the planet should anyone do that. Fork a shell process if you have to or re-write whatever you have in awk or perl or whatever - the result will be MUCH clearer and more robust and almost certainly faster and briefer too.